# How do I escape pipe "|" character in query string KSH Linux?

Tags: linux, ksh

I need to execute this query in sqlplus:

```
q="
SELECT  count(*) cnt FROM all_tables WHERE UPPER(OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME)=UPPER('$tab_')"
```

but pipe "|" get interpreted in KSH:

```
echo $q

SELECT  count(*) cnt FROM all_tables WHERE UPPER(OWNER  '.'  TABLE_NAME)=UPPER('STGDATA.T_DEL_RW_FIFO_PL_HIS_SC')
```

How do I escape them so query can be executed in sqlplus?

Comment: `echo "$q"` should solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have linux to test but on openbsd ksh it doesn't make it disappear

```
$ ./escape.sh
/bin/ksh -> SELECT count(*) cnt FROM all_tables WHERE UPPER(OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME)=UPPER('')
$ cat escape.sh
#!/bin/sh
q="SELECT  count(*) cnt FROM all_tables WHERE UPPER(OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME)=UPPER('$tab_')"
echo $SHELL "->" $q
```

but try the normal backslash escape like

```
$ echo \|\|
||
```

if what you have there is a multiline string (cause i see that line break between " and the SELECT i would suggest using a cat << EOF construct.